# No longer update apps or use safari

Tags: safari, macos, mac-appstore, permission

I recently migrated my macbook 12" to a macbook pro (touchbar). I used the migration assistant to transfer a backup from the old mac to the new one. At first all was successful apart from a slight issue with the incompatible OS version between the two machines. (I had to update before migrating)

I am running Sierra(10.12.5 (16F73)) on the new machine. I am now facing a number of issues with the machine, I would guess its a permission thing. I *think* but cannot be certain that **vmware fusion** has something to do with the issue because it was the last program I tried to install from the old backup before seeing issues. (I had to kill the installation)

- safari opens and appears to load a page, but just sits there - no matter what the url is. Chrome and Firefox work perfectly well and other programs do not have an issue getting an internet connection.
- mac store updates do not work, when I click update on an app, I see: "We could not complete your update. Unknown error"

I noticed that the owner of my application (located at `/Library/*`) is as follows:

`drwxr-xr-x@   3 root          wheel    102 30 Jun  2016 Safari.app`

1. Should root own these applications?
2. How can I debug this issue with safari and the app store updates?
3. Any thoughts what could cause behaviour like this?

So far, I have tried, neither worked:

1. Repairing disk permissions using the 'first aid' tool in disk utility.
2. Reinstall OS (restart, `cmd+r`, Reinstall OS)

Thanks

Comment: Create a temporary user account and see if the problem occurs in this account. Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: only tried chrome and firefox, as mentioned above. will try a new user account now

Comment: creating a new user accounts solves the issue with safari. so i guess this is a user level permission issue?

Comment: Either that or a .plist file or files corruption problem. Have you cleared all the caches & cookies in Safari? Preferences > Privacy > Manage Website Data. [This page](http://osxdaily.com/2016/01/17/empty-cache-safari-mac-os-x/) can help with some of the finer details.

Comment: thanks for your reply. interestingly when i try to remove all my cookies, they re-appear again - which is very odd.

Comment: [This thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/30392481#30392481) has an answer from Linc Davis with Terminal commands to reset user permissions and other stuff. BTW, have you booted the Mac into Safe mode? (Hold down Shift while booting, then let go when Apple logo appears.)

Comment: Safari.app shouldn't be located at /Library/! Or is this just a typo?

Comment: so my applications are located here in the terminal: `/Users/archienorman/Library` however, in finder they seem to be here: `/Applications`, however if i navigate to `/Users/archienorman/Library` in finder, i only see three applications. am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @IconDaemon - you comment solved it.

Step 1: Follow this [link](https://discussions.apple.com/message/30392481#30392481) and run the terminal command.

Step 2: Restart the Mac in safe mode.